# My app has to be published first? But it's still under development

Tags: support, stackapps, testing, placeholder, posts

Okay, I want to build an App that allows me to create questions on Stack Exchange. I registered it here on Stack Apps but now when I want to create a question I get this message:

```
{
  "error_message": "Applications must have a registered Stack Apps post to write",
  "error_id": 403,
  "error_name": "access_denied"
}
```

On my profile the Stack Apps Post is set to `Not set` and it tells me that my app has to be published first:

> Stack Apps Post
>
> `Not Set`
>
> When you've published your application, it should be listed on Stack Apps with the `app` or `script` tags.

But how should I publish something, that I could not initially test? And how would I publish my App (not that I would be ready for this now)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's a bit of a Catch-22.  Work around it by:

1. Make a [app](/questions/tagged/app) (or [script](/questions/tagged/script)) post for your app (or script).
2. Also tag it with [placeholder](/questions/tagged/placeholder).
3. And put "`PLACEHOLDER -` " at the beginning of the title.
4. Provide a summary of what your app will do.

Also, indicate in the post text that the app is not yet ready for prime time.

---

This has already been done a few times, for example:

- ["Chatdump - a site monitor (placeholder)"](https://stackapps.com/q/4557/7653)
- ["A small Stack Overflow browser for Android, for a school project (Placeholder)"](https://stackapps.com/q/4536/7653)

---

Warning: **Don't abuse this, or create an essentially empty post and not update it expeditiously**.  Otherwise [the question will be closed](https://stackapps.com/questions/7490/what-to-do-about-the-tsunami-of-placeholder-apps-created-because-of-a-poorly-wri) and, if not corrected, quickly deleted.

Comment: Oh, I was wondering why people were creating placeholder questions. Thanks for explaining this because I was considering flagging them.

Comment: @jmort253 Ok, I can surely do this. How will this then be linked to my App and its identifier? With the "Chatdump" example there is no reference to any Stackapps app.

Comment: @Besi, go to [your app page](http://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/view/2690) -- which only you can see -- and press the `Edit This App` button near the bottom.  Then paste a link to [your app post](http://stackapps.com/q/4575/7653) in the `Stack Apps Post` box and submit the changes.

Comment: Can you please explain the "placeholder" close reason, then?

Comment: @gparyani, see [the inaugural post](https://stackapps.com/a/7591/7653).  That close reason is a response to a rash of questions that never showed any effort whatsoever.  Best I can tell, it's actually been used about 3 times, and I guarantee that no one who has read *this* Q&A has had that close reason applied to them.  In practice, no one here has made any effort to close all stagnant [placeholder] questions -- of which many remain.  And if such a question *is* put on hold, it's not "just procedure" and they can't just fix it by removing placeholder indications.