# How to get write_access for stackexchange API for a web app

Tags: support

I'm trying to integrate the stack exchange API into my web app so I can fetch all posts as well as I can post answer or comments on them. I have successfully got `access_token` for **no_expiry** and **private_info** and they are working as well. But when I'm trying to get the `access_token` for **write access**, I'm getting an error as:

```
 Applications must have a registered Stack Apps post to write
```

Please let me know if anybody is also facing same issue or know how to get access token for **write_access**.

Comment: See https://stackapps.com/a/4574/34061; you might need to add a link to this question to your app [here](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/).